activar un menu que solo se activa pasando con el puntero
estoy haciendo una rutina automatica en un sitio web con python, es un sitio para crear pruebas pero es engorroso y espero poder automatizarlo. el tema esta en que por defecto las preguntas de alternativas vienen con 3 alternativas a, b y c para agregar la alternativa D debo dar clik en + un menu que solo se activa cuando pasas con el puntero sobre el
este es el html que solo se activa al pasar con el puntero
<div class="edu-container-menu-questions noprint sortable ui-sortable-handle" data-id="3205443">
<button onclick="remove(3205443, 129084, '2')" class="pull-right edu-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Eliminar Pregunta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button onclick="cancelQuestion(3205443, 129084)" class="pull-right edu-cancel" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Desactivar Pregunta"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open " aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button onclick="addAlternative(3205443, 129084)" class="pull-right edu-addAlternative" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Ingresar alternativa"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<button onclick="showCharacteristicsTable(3205443, 129084)" class="pull-right edu-showCharacteristics" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Mostrar Tabla de Características"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

en esta parte he probado varias formas
       # Navegar al botón de agregar alternativa y hacer clic
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'edu-addAlternative')]"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)  # Esperar a que la alternativa D aparezca

otra
# Encontrar la pregunta
    question_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tu-selector-de-pregunta']")

    # Crear una instancia de ActionChains
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    # Mover el puntero del mouse sobre la pregunta
    actions.move_to_element(question_element).perform()

    # Esperar un breve momento para asegurarse de que el menú se haya activado
    time.sleep(1)

    # Agregar la alternativa D
    driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 3)  # 3 tabs para llegar al botón de añadir alternativa D
    driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)  # Esperar para que aparezca la alternativa D

otra
        # Encontrar el botón que activa el menú desplegable
    add_alternative_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pull-right edu-addAlternative']")

    # Hacer clic en el botón para activar el menú desplegable
    add_alternative_button.click()

no se si estan del todo bien
el caso es que si ejecuto el programa y pongo el puntero en cada pregunta funciona bien pero si quito el puntero no se activa el menu y se congela todo. aun no se como activar el menu. todo el codigo se basa en ejecutarno el chrome.
Saludos!

eso de activar los menu al pasar el puntero, esta completamente desfasado.... con la implementacion de que asi todo es tactil ahora lo habitual es el click para abrir los menu...
